# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rfc822'

Tags: python-3.x, rfc822

I trying to read my email python version 3.6.9 and pip3 version 9.0.1. when i run the following script it returns the error shows below. I try to install rfc822 with pip and pip3. Can you please help me to solve this issue.

Many thanks Erik

**ERROR**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/webapp/git/RA Functions/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import rfc822
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rfc822'
```

**CODE**

```
import poplib
import string, random
import rfc822
from io import StringIO

def readMail(): 
    SERVER = "pop.gmail.com"
    USER = "myemail@gmail.com"
    PASSWORD = "mypassword"

    # connect to server
    server = poplib.POP3(SERVER)

    # login
    server.user(USER)
    server.pass_(PASSWORD)

    # list items on server
    resp, items, octets = server.list()

    for i in range(0,10):
        id, size = string.split(items[i])
        resp, text, octets = server.retr(id)

        text = string.join(text, "\n")
        file = StringIO.StringIO(text)

        message = rfc822.Message(file)

        for k, v in message.items():
            print(k, "=", v)

readMail()
```

Comment: What did you try for installation? try this 'pip install plone.rfc822'. If it is generating error tell us about that error

Comment: No just pip3 install rfc822 and pip install rfc822

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This module is **deprecated** since version 2.3: The `email` package should be used in preference to the `rfc822` module. This module is present only to maintain backward compatibility, and has been removed in Python 3.

For more information visit this : [Deprecated Link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/rfc822.html)

But here is another module which is `plone.rfc822`

This package provides primitives for turning content objects described by zope.schema fields into RFC (2)822 style messages. It utilizes the Python standard library’s email module.

For installation:  `pip install plone.rfc822`

For information visit this: [Active Link](https://pypi.org/project/plone.rfc822/)